# Can't connect to WinRM on Domain controller

Tags: active-directory, azure, domain-controller, windows-server-2016, winrm

I have set up a domain controller server on Azure with Windows Server 2016. Now I want to connect to this server using PSSession.

WinRM is enabled, all firewall rules are ok, inbound rules on Azure network security group too, but I can't connect to the server.

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server a.b.c.d failed with the
>   following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify
>   that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is
>   accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the
>   WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
>   default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits
>   access to remote computers within the same local subnet.

I can connect to this server using RDP only, but no success with WinRM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: in a admin powershell what does "winrm get winrm/config" look correct? AllowRemoteShellAccess = True, correct port HTTP/HTTPS that are in your firewall rules, would check that no GPO is forcing any different powershell settings

Answer (score 1):

> I can connect to this server using RDP only, but no success with
>   WinRM.

To Winrm Azure VM, we should add port 5985 to Azure VM NSG inbound rules. Also we should add port 5985 to Windows server 2016 windows firewall inbound rules.

We can follow this step to enable winrm for this VM:

1.Add port 5985 to Azure VM NSG inbound rules.
2.Add port 5985 to Azure VM windows firewall inbound rules.
3.Enable Winrm settings in Azure VM, use this command `winrm quickconfig`
4.Add trust host to your local PC, use this command

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value *
```

5.Then use this script to Winrm your VM:

```
$username = 'jason'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://13.xx.xx.89:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {get-process}
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://support.auvik.com/hc/en-us/articles/204424994-How-to-enable-WinRM-with-domain-controller-Group-Policy-for-WMI-monitoring).

Comment: As I said: "WinRM is enabled, all firewall rules are ok, inbound rules on Azure network security group too, but I can't connect to the server."

Comment: @zairhenrique can you telnet your port 5985?